# Deleting .zsh_history file safe?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, zsh

Is deleting your .zsh_history file safe? I want to avoid it but when I'm updating Android Studio there's some sort of conflict and it won't complete unless I delete the file. I should mention that I'm on macOS and had to change the default shell to zsh from bash for the Catalina update.

[Android Studio Update Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOZRA.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.zsh_history` keeps the history of commands you entered in zsh. So yes, it's safe to delete, the only thing that happens is that your history will be gone.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the file that Android Studio wants to delete is *not* your zsh history. The relative path is Contents/plugins/terminal/.zsh_history, so the full path is (probably) /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/terminal, and if you look the file is likely to be 0 bytes.

Your history is most likely in your home directory.